# Organize objects by date range in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, date, data-structures, dictionary

I have a `List` of `Stat` objects and each `Stat` has a `Date` field. This list may be very large. What I would like to do is organize these objects into date ranges (weeks to be specific) efficiently. So, if two objects occur in the same week, they go into the same `List`. For simplicity, the 'week' intervals are already defined so you don't have to worry about coming up with the ranges.

So here is my current approach. I have a `LinkedHashMap<Date, List<Stat>>` that contains all the dates I need in ascending order and each entry is initialized with an empty `ArrayList`. I am thinking for each `Stat`, iterating through the entire entrySet of the Map, and keeping track of the closest Date that the stat is also greater than or equal to. Then it would be something like `map.get(closestDate).add(stat)`.

It seems like there should be a better way to do this. Perhaps create something like a `findClosestKeyGreaterThanOrEqualTo` so that I don't have to iterate through the entire map every time?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be clearer about exactly what you want? Apparently new Stats should be inserted in the same week as the one whose data is closest?

Comment: So the map keys could be `Mar 3`, `Mar 10`, `Mar 17`, etc. If a stat has date `Mar 11`, it will go in the list map by the `Mar 10` date. `Mar 10` is the closest date that `Mar 11` is also greater than... I guess the hypothetical function name could be more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of a [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) (like `TreeMap`) which has [very useful methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorEntry(K)) exactly for this purpose.

Initialize your map with all the values that you have computed and empty lists for each:

```
NavigableMap<Date, List<Stat>> map = new TreeMap<>();
// add all your weekly values associated with empty lists
```

Then for each of your `Stat` objects, find the proper list simply by:

```
final Entry<Date, List<Stat>> entry = map.floorEntry(stat.getDate());
entry.getValue().add(stat);
```

Comment: I came up with this just before you posted it. But you explained it better than me so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You're right, I now realize that you've answered your own question faster than I did, and you referred to the correct `floorKey` method rather than the wrong `floorEntry` that I used; I'm getting old... :)

Comment: @jlars62 I edited the code snippet to show my initial intention regarding `floorEntry`, just for the record.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answers.

I am going to go with a [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) as the `floorKey` function is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do, assuming you can already convert Date into a `weekId`:

- Create a `Map<WeekId, List<Stat>>`
- Iterate through your original `List<Stat>` once and in each cycle calculate `weekId` from the date, then add `Stat` to an appropriate List by retrieving it from the `Map` by `weekId` (create one if it does not exist and add it to the map)

You should have a desired result in the map at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all dates are rounded to the nearest week. Then use a `getWeek(stat)` function and insert the stat into the map there. A simple `HashMultimap` will do.

You need to deal with the issue of hash codes and equality. Say I have a data type

```
class Pair {
   public int x;
   public int y;
   // obvious constructor
}
```

Observe:

```
new Pair(1,2) == new Pair(1,2) // false
new Pair(1,2).equals(new Pair(1,2)) // false
```

And if you use them as keys in a hash map they will be different keys.

You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` to overcome this.

For `Date` we observe:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
}
```

Hashcode will be defined correspondingly. So if you key off of `Date` you will only get what you want if the dates *agree to the milliscecond*.

Therefore a

```
HashMultimap<Date, Stat> map;
```

Is fine, but you should programmatically observe the convention that all dates are rounded down to the nearest week. Then do:

```
Date key = roundToWeek(stat);
map.insert(key, stat);
```

And you should be good.